# How to pass the Validation.Errors to the child object?

Tags: wpf

I have one control which is derived from CONTROL and i have some additional properties within the control. And within this control template i have the same control like below.

```
<Controls:FieldControl Value={Binding Path=Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay >
<ControlTemplate>
<Controls:FieldControl x:Name="ctrl" Value="{Binding Path=Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" Validation.ErrorTemplate={dynamicResource myErrorTemplate} />
</ControlTemplate>
 </Controls:FieldControl>
```

On Validation Errors i am able to see the error in the parent control, but it is not passed to the child control("ctrl").How can i have the errors in the child control and how to i apply the errorTemplate for the child control.

Comment: Please see the [`ControlTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. You are clearly confused about the use of the `ControlTemplate` class. Not only would your displayed code not work, but what you are doing there is absolutely pointless. There is no parent control and no child control. If you had declared the `ControlTemplate` property correctly, then you would just have one control with its `ControlTemplate` set to another copy of the same thing... pointless. What are you *trying* to achieve with this?

Comment: I have so many templates for the child control, I know clearly the concept of ControlTemplate, please reply if you know the answer for passing the Validation.Errors from top control to its control template.

Comment: [*Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) Please edit your question and correct your code to show that you have a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. As I already stated, there is *no* child or parent shown, so your question does not currently make sense.